Passing data between pages in React Router using the Action and Loaders
Using React Router 6, and the createBrowserRouter method.
I really like the way the Loaders and Actions can separate data fetching from the React components. However, I'm unclear on how to properly pass data between pages.
For example, I have a login page. The user submits the form, and I handle it in an Action, hit an api with the login details, and then I want to send the user to another page with the data from the login request.
function LoginAction async ({request}) {
  const response = await callLoginAPI(request.body);// or whatever
  if (response.ok) {
  // where do I put the response data?
    return redirect("/user-page");
  }

}

There are ways to inject redux into the action, but they seem hacky. We can't pass data through the redirect. Can I return a POST request with the data in the body? That doesn't seem like it's a thing. Maybe I'm missing some functionality of React Router.
I guess the other option is to use the useActionData hook inside my Login component, then update redux from there, and redirect if the action returns data.

Why can't you just dispatch to your store from the action? This seems more "whatever state lib you're using"-related then to do with react router.

@super Actions are outside of the component: no hooks available. There are work-around, but they feel hacky ActionGetter(PageAction) kind of thing

You are not forced to use hooks. They are just a convecience for usage inside components. You can just go store.dispatch(...).

Route loaders/actions for the current route, not generally for passing data between pages/routes. That said, you can pass data in a redirect. See my answer here for details.

My last comment lead me to an answer: submit to the same Page component and use the useActionData hook. Conceptually, it's similar to traditional server-side form submits: the POST request goes back to the same url the form is on. It ends up looking like this:
function Login() {
  const submitData = useActionData();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if(submitData) navigate("/next-page");
  }, [submitData])
  <form>
//...
  </form>
}

function LoginAction({request}) {
  const response = await callLoginAPI(request.body);// or whatever
  if (response.ok) {
    return submit(response.json());
  }
  return null;
}

I don't love sticking conditional data in the useEffect, it feels like a not-elegant way to separate GET and POST request handling, but it works and keeps the fetching out of the component at least.
